# What does function (i, val) mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I was just wondering what (i, val) means in this function and what it is passing?

```
function boldToggler(itemid) {
    $(itemid).css("font-weight", function(i, val) {
        return val == "bold" ? "normal" : "bold";
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about check http://api.jquery.com/css/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`.css( propertyName, function(index, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2):

> function(index, value) - A function returning the value to set. this
>   is the current element. Receives the **index** position of the element in
>   the set and the **old value** as arguments.

For example, suppose you had the following HTML:

```
<div style="font-weight: normal" />
<div style="font-weight: bold" />
```

And you execute:

```
$("div").css("font-weight", function(i, val) {
    return val == "bold" ? "normal" : "bold";
});
```

`function(i, val)` will be executed once for each `div` element. In the **first** execution, `i` will be 0, and `val` is the old value of the `font-weight` property, that is, `normal`. In the **second**, `i` will be 1, and `val` is the old value of the `font-weight` property, that is, `bold`.

Comment: Hi Joao, thanks for your answer, but what is the index position?

Comment: so i is a counter- so it will add for every execution, so you could change the rules for each item depending on execution order basically?

Comment: @Joe: `i` is more like an index, it's the position of the element that you are iterating in the HTML. So if you were iterating over three `div`, the first `div`s will have index `0`, the second `1`, and the third `2`.

Answer (score 2):

In case of `.css()`, `function(index, value)`:

> A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

You can find about this here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

See extract from [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
.css( propertyName, function(index, value) )

function(index, value)
```

A function returning the value to set. this is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old value as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

i and val are parameters.

You can see that function has no name - that means that the value is function itself - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)

Since it is starting with "$" i think it is jQuery.
Look jQuery docs for css method - which values does it pass to finction.

That method would call the function over each element it has (here would be the only one with given ID, but it can be "all elements with class given" or such) and use the result.